# Region/State Select List not alphabetical

Tags: select, country-regions

We are using Turkish cities in the Region field and the select dropdown for region/state in the address field in admin customer new address is generating the list alphabetically but in the frontend, the list is not listed alphabetically the English letters are alphabetically listed but the Turkish characters such as İ, Ş are shown after the English letters.

How can I make it list all regions/States alphabetically?

Comment: You must be add first later a-z or A-Z

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand, can you explain please? @Abdul